# Spring MVC, Thymeleaf URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url, thymeleaf

I have `settings page` and controller for him:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/password/change", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String changePassword(Model model) {
    return "account/changepassword";
}
```

On this page there is `header` which contains link on `myaccount`:
`<a class="link" th:href="${currentUser.nickname}"><li class="li">User profile</li></a>`
But if I open `settings page` link on header have URL: `localhost:8080/settings/password/change/profilename`. Instead of this I need URL like: `localhost:8080/profilename`. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `/settings/password/change/profilename` because `th:href="${currentUser.nickname}"` creates a relative URL to the current path: `<a href="profilename"/>`

Instead, try using this [Thymeleaf syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) in order to build a context-relative URL:

```
<a th:href="@{/{profilename}(profilename=${currentUser.nickname})}">link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me!